# Running nagios on kubernetes fails with "Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 401"

Tags: kubernetes, helm, kubernetes-helm, nagios

I am trying to run nagios on my kubernetes (k3s) cluster. I have created a helm chart (see below) but every time I try to run it, it fails the livenliness probes with a "Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 401"

```yml
replicaCount: 1

image:
  repository: jasonrivers/nagios
  pullPolicy: Always
  tag: ""

imagePullSecrets: []
nameOverride: "nagios"
fullnameOverride: "nagios"

serviceAccount:
  create: true
  annotations: {}
  name: "nagios-acc"

podAnnotations: {}

podSecurityContext: {}

securityContext: {}

service:
  type: NodePort
  # if we set this to 8080 we get connection refused
  port: 80
  targetPort: 80
  nodePort: 30008

ingress:
  enabled: true
  className: "traefik"
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
  hosts:
    - host: nagios.k8s.local
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
  tls: 
    - secretName: nagios-tls
      hosts:
        - nagios.k8s.local
resources: {}


autoscaling:
  enabled: false
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 1
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 80


nodeSelector: {}

tolerations: []

affinity: {}

name: nagios.k8s.local

# added custom probes to mitigate the 401 error
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    httpHeaders:
    - name: Authorization
      value: 'Basic bmFnaW9zYWRtaW46bmFnaW9zCg=='

livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    httpHeaders:
    - name: Authorization
      value: 'Basic bmFnaW9zYWRtaW46bmFnaW9zCg=='
```